# PARSE + Unity3d freezing from a query

Tags: c#, parse-platform, unity-game-engine

> ```
> public ParseObject TheRow;
> public void GetCharacterData(){
>     string UserName=ParseUser.CurrentUser.Username;
>     var query = ParseObject.GetQuery ("Character").WhereEqualTo ("user", UserName);
>     query.FirstAsync().ContinueWith(t =>{
>         TheRow = t.Result;
>             PlayerPrefs.SetString("UserName",TheRow.Get<string>("user"));
>             PlayerPrefs.SetString("Some",TheRow.Get<string>("SomeData")); // No save data ( I use PlayerPrefs from an other thread than MainThread )
>             Debug.Log(PlayerPrefs.GetString("UserName"));
>     }); Debug.Log("UserName",TheRow.Get<string>("user")); // Null reference
> }
> ```

Why?
Assigning t.Result to TheRow in an asynchronous block of code but I'm trying to access it outside that block, so TheRow is going to be null...Parse methods need some time ...

How can I rewrite that?

Comment: This is freezing because you are accessing the `.Result` on the query. You should wrap your code in a continuation (`query'FirstAsync().ContinueWith` instead, so it gets called when the query is completed.

Comment: On something like that I get this error: TrySetSetString can only be called from the main thread.
Constructors and field initializers will be executed from the loading thread when loading a scene.
Don't use this function in the constructor or field initializers, instead move initialization code to the Awake or Start function.

Comment: You'll need to see how to Marshall the continuation back to the main thread. I can't remember off the top of my head, but I think it's `.ConfigureAwait(false);` not sure, I'm mobile right now so can't look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After one sleepless night I fixed it and I made this API. 
PS: Thanks for your help anyway :)

> **https://github.com/RealStyle12/Parse-and-Facebook-Unity3d**

Answer (score -1):

Try changing:

```
ParseObject TheRow = query.FirstAsync().Result;
```

to:

```
ParseObject TheRow = await query.FirstAsync();
```

EDIT:
Reading the manual for the method (http://parse.com/docs/dotnet/api/html/T_Parse_ParseQuery_1.htm)

Looks like your probelm is the .Result blocking an async task somewhere, as example all use await.

Comment: I don't think Unity uses .net 4.5. When I was last using it, await wasn't available. This why I recommended a Continuation on the Task

Comment: Unity3d does use .NET 4.5.1 only in Universal Windows Applications ( Windows Store ) in all the other platform supports .NET 2.0/3.5

Comment: I'll take your words on this, I was simply looking at the examples from the manual for ParseQuery.